# Stack smashing detected when trying to copy one string to another using pointers

Tags: c, pointers

I am trying to copy one string to another using pointers, but stack smashing error occurred, while the string is copied successfully.

Here's the code below,

```
#include <stdio.h>
void strcat(char *str1, char *str2) {
    char *run = str1;
    while(*run !='\0')
        run++;
    while(*str2 !='\0') {
        *run = *str2;
        run++;
        str2++;
    }
    *run = '\0';
}
int main() {
    char s[] = "hellomojo";
    char t[] = "world";

    printf("\ns :%s", s);
    printf("\n t :%s",t);
    strcat(s, t);
    printf("\ns after:%s",s);
}
```

Is it due to illegal access to memory not pointed by pointers?

Comment: The error means you are writing to memory you don't own. Will likely happen if you try to copy a string longer than the one you specified for str1. In this case, it could be cos you are copying the string into memory location assigned to a string constant. Try allocating the new memory with the memory of both str1 + str2 and assign the pointer to str after concatenating.

Answer (score 2):

This `char s[]="hellomojo";` is basically the same as `char s[10]="hellomojo";`. It is an array of 10 characters (including the NUL-terminator). You cannot store more than 10 characters in it. But you concatenate the other string with this, writing into illegal memory locations beyond the array. This invokes [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Hence the stack smashing problem.

The fix would be to increase the size of the first array like:

```
char s[32] = "hellomojo"; /* 32 chosen arbitrary */
```

Comment: so,how is it implemented in system library.do I need to allocate memory before copying

Comment: You need to make sure you have adequate space in the destination string before concatenating. A fix would be to increase the size of the destination array as shown in my answer. Also, `s` is an array, not a pointer. You can't change its size on the fly.

Comment: the solution is fine,but who knows the string's length to be copied,it may be greater than that or even less(wastage of space),so how do you generalize it?or may be in the library how did they do it?

Comment: In that case, what you're looking for are pointers with `malloc`,`realloc` etc. Something like `char *s = malloc(strlen("hellomojo") + strlen("world") + 1); if(s) {strcpy(s, "hellomojo"); strcat(s, "world"); printf("%s", s); free(s); }`

Answer (score 0):

Working with what little code was supplied, my guess would be that at least one of those char pointers doesn't have enough allocated memory, or does not have a null terminating character as expected.

You show the code, but what is the output and the error message? With more information, it would be easier to debug.